# Raspberry Pi Camera Module As A Streaming Webcam Commands

Tags: raspbian, camera, streaming

```
mmal: Skipping frame 2 to restart at frame 5
mmal: Skipping frame 6 to restart at frame 10
mmal: Skipping frame 11 to restart at frame 16
mmal: Skipping frame 17 to restart at frame 22
mmal: Skipping frame 23 to restart at frame 29
mmal: Skipping frame 30 to restart at frame 35
mmal: Skipping frame 36 to restart at frame 42
mmal: Skipping frame 49  to restart at frame 55
```

i was looking at this site: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/how-to-build-and-run-mjpg-streamer-on-the-raspberry-pi/page/10

i was following the steps and when i see these lines of commands i don't understand why 
it skip frame 2 to restart at frame 5 why not skip frame 3 to restart at frame 4?

can someone enlighten me? thanks in advance